# How do you scrape images with Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have tried many solutions but I am unable to scrape images with Scrapy. Can Someone can teach me how to scrape images using Scrapy?

Here is my complete code.

Spider:

```
import scrapy
import datetime
from ..items import ImagesItem
class image(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'img'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.allhindilyrics.com/lyrics/nachan-nu-jee-karda-from-angrezi-medium'
    ]

def parse(self, response):

    items = ImagesItem()
    image_url = response.xpath('//*[@id="polular"]/div[1]/div/div/div/a/img').extract()
    items['image_urls'] = image_url
    return items
```

My `items.py`:

```
import scrapy
class ImagesItem(scrapy.Item):
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    images = scrapy.Field()
```

I have also enabled a pipeline with file storage.
Please help me with this as I am new to Python and I really need help.

Comment: Try using Images pipeline instead of files pipeline?

Comment: Yes I am using images pipeline but its not working

Comment: you have defined images store and etc?

Comment: yes I am able to scrapy all images of a web page but how can I scrape a single image from web page. Please Help me out on this. And if possible please provide me some code to scrap a single image from a web page by xpath selector. Please its a request.

Comment: I realize the default behavior is to download image_urls if it is working with a list and not with a single image try making the single image into a list. so you could do image_url=xpath('')[integer].extract() for a single list then item['image_url']=image_url

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#